# No dhtreader in java.library.path

Tags: java, c, maven, java-native-interface, raspberry-pi3

I try to get this maven [projekt](https://bitbucket.org/Temdegon/greenhouse) to run on the Raspberry Pi 3 but the DHT11 sensor gives me the following error:

```
sudo java -classpath '.:classes:*:classes:/opt/pi4j/lib/*' com.epam.llpd.greenhouse.web.ServerStarter

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no dhtreader in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at com.epam.llpd.greenhouse.sensor.Sensor.<clinit>(Sensor.java:16)
    at com.epam.llpd.greenhouse.PiHardwareController$1.run(PiHardwareController.java:132)
```

In the folder `\src\main\java\com\epam\llpd\greenhouse\sensor` there is the `dhtreader.c` file.

I did compile a binary objekt with the following command:

```
gcc -o dhtreader.so -lc -shared -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7-oracle-arm-vfp-hflt/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7-oracle-arm-vfp-hflt/include/linux dhtreader.c -l bcm2835
```

The `dhtreader.so` is placed in the same folder as the `.jar`.

The dhtreader.c file is a common C class specific for the Raspberry Pi to use the DHT11 and DHT22 sensor and it is used in many Raspberry Pi projects and has alot of sources like [this one](https://code.ga-fl.net/cgz/jacuzzi/tree/913b3e809831b2e6a04f9e31c52bf03ea4176d38/var/jacuzzi/lib/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code-master/Adafruit_DHT_Driver_Python).

This C class (dhtreader.c) is used via. JNI/C but it just doesn't work because of the error above.

I allready tried to set the `java.library.path` with the following method in the java main:

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path", "./");
```

That didn't help. Instead i added `-Djava.library.path=./` to the java command:

```
sudo java -classpath '.:classes:*:classes:/opt/pi4j/lib/*' com.epam.llpd.greenhouse.web.ServerStarter -Djava.library.path=./
```

But that didn't help neither.

Now i'm stuck and don't know how to add the `dhtreader.so` to the `java.library.path`.

**How do i add the `dhtreader.so` to the `java.library.path`?**

I asked in the [Raspberry Pi StackExchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/48064/no-dhtreader-in-java-library-path) first but they thought that it's off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to simply rename `dhtreader.so` to `libdhtreader.so`.

Indeed when we call `System.loadLibrary("foo")` in java the expected name of the library is:

- **Windows:** `foo.dll`
- **Unix/Linux:** `libfoo.so`
- **Mac:** `libfoo.jnilib`

Try to launch it as next:

```
sudo java -Djava.library.path=./lib -classpath '.:classes:*:classes:/opt/pi4j/lib/*' com.epam.llpd.greenhouse.web.ServerStarter
```

NB: The command above assumes that your lib is located in the lib directory that is itself located in the directory where the command has been launched.

Comment: I took the existing dhtreader.so and renamed it and placed it in the .jar folder. That didn't work. In which folders should i place it? Do i have so set the java.library.path for the java command? Or did i miss something else?

Comment: You where right with the first problem (libdhtreader.so). The second problem was to write the -Djava.library.path direct behind sudo java and not at the end behind the main class. Now a third problem was that the libdhtreader.so wasn't compiled with the bcm2835 buts thats another story. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, i noticed. That's why i realiced it ;)