# UnsatisfiedLinkError for libMagick.so.10 while using JMagick

Tags: java, imagemagick, jmagick

I am trying to run a program which uses JMagick. I have added the native library libJMagick.so as well as libMagick.so.10 (64 bit, matching my system's architecture) to my java.library.path. But when I am trying to run the program I am getting following error:

> libJMagick.so: libMagick.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory

From error, it looks like it is finding the libJMagick.so file, but it is not able to find libMagick.so.10, although it is present in java.library.path.

I have ImageMagick installed in my system.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37514050/1997376 it may help

Answer (score 0):

When you copy the .so files, Please do it in respective folders. So that the Java application will load the libraries available for the usage. This is all about your configuration issue. Where to store the shared object files, They should be available on the path.